# Use Spring form:checkboxes with Map and entering manual values

Tags: spring, dictionary, spring-form

Is there any way, using the spring form:checkboxes tag, to iterate over a Map and adding manually the values that go with the selected keys?

I cant seem to find any information on this. the best info i've found about the use of this tag is on [this page](http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-form-checkboxes/). it got me going on how to implement some of the code that i need but it doesnt show me how to send the value of the map as well, not just the key.

To complicate matters, I need to be able to enter a value manually in the form.

any way to do this or do I have to find an alternative solution?

Comment: You should add code your tried, because obviouly the example page works fine ... As currently written, your question is *unclear*

Comment: the code i have at the moment, isnt a good example. I'll ask like this. is following statement (coming from the mentioned page) always true:

"Map’s keys will be used as values of checkboxes, and Map’s values will be used as labels of checkboxes."

Or is there any way to use the keys as the labels and entering a corresponding value in an input tag, then sending all this data to a Map-property set in the path of form:checkboxes.

I guess my question can be very unclear but i hope you understand what i need.

Comment: If you want to enter a value, checkboxes are propably not the best solution ... Try to design the form, without that it will be hard to help you.

Comment: thanks for the feedback! At first I just needed to select a couple of values from a list and send them to another list and so I used the form:checkboxes. it works perfectly (maybe there are better methods but i'm glad i got it working in the first place!). Now that I want to add a value for every selected item I need to switch to a map, but as i already was afraid of, checkboxes will need to go then.

Comment: What is your requirement: fetch some values from an input list and optionnally add a new value (kind of good old *combobox*), or input a new value *linked* (through a Map) for each (or some) element from the input list ?

Comment: the second one! In my view i show a list of objects ('ingredients') of which i can select some and enter a bigdecimal (the quantity to use of the selected ingredient). both then need to be safed (and linked to each other) so I was thinking of a map.

Comment: I thing I can now understand what you want. If you add to your question the form with the checkboxes, the post method in controller (even without the quantities) and the domain or form object (with or without the quantities) I could give you a solution.